# Change date time from dd/mn/yyyy to dS F, Y h: m A

Tags: php, date

I' am trying to convert **16/06/2014 8:00 am** to **16th June, 2014 8:00 AM**

**This is the format of the original date.**

> $date_time = '16/06/2014 8:00 am';

**What does that above give me**

> 01st January 1970 12:01 AM

This is the code in place

```
$date_time = date("dS F Y h:m A", strtotime($date_time ));
```

Comment: When `strtotime()` fails you, use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) Actually, you're better off with `DateTime` much of the time in PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat():](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date_time = '16/06/2014 8:00 am';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:ia', $date_time);

echo $date->format('dS F Y h:m A');
```

**Note:** you are using `m` here, which is a **month** representation. You should use `i` instead for the number of minutes:

```
dS F Y H:i A
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `/` slashes with `-` minus

```
$date_time = '16/06/2014 8:00 am';
$date_time = str_replace('/', '-', $date_time);    
$date_time = date("dS F Y h:i A", strtotime($date_time )); 
                          //here change m with i for minutes, m is for months

echo $date_time;
//output 16th June 2014 08:00 AM
```

Working sample [**`here`**](http://codepad.org/mYSz9OZ7)